# prevent plot_ly reordering matrix

Tags: r, plotly

I recently updated R and Rstudio and naturally now a load of scripts I had written are broken.

Specifically one thing that's causing me issues is the script below. Previously it used to output a heatmap *exactly* as it appeared in the csv of values I gave it to make the matrix. Now the later versions seem to have changed how they order things. Its now ordering the columns and their labels in ascending numeric order, which is putting them out of order. How can I prevent it rearranging columns, or specify that it treat them as I provided them?

The minor aesthetic issues aren't so much of an issue.

Here's the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)
# Read in data
library(readr)


adjwallace <- read.csv() # see the link for the actual data http://pastebin.com/bBLs8uLt


rownames(adjwallace_recluster)[17] <- "Species" #Rename STree
names(adjwallace_recluster)[17] <- "Species"


# Preferences for xaxis
font.pref <- list(
  size = 20,
  family = "Arial, sans-serif",
  color = "black"
)

x.axisSettings <- list(
  title = "",
  zeroline = FALSE,
  showline = FALSE,
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  tickfont = font.pref,
  showgrid = TRUE
)

# Preferences for yaxis
y.axisSettings <- list(
  title = "",
  zeroline = FALSE,
  showline = FALSE,
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  tickfont = font.pref,
  showgrid = TRUE
)

margins <- list(
  l = 50,
  r = 10,
  b = 50,
  t = 10,
  pad = 1
)

# Plot graph as a heatmap
p <-plot_ly(z = ~data.matrix(adjwallace),
        colors = "YlOrRd",
        name = "Adjusted Wallace Coefficients",
        x = names(adjwallace),
        y = names(adjwallace),
        colorbar = list(title = "Adjusted Wallace <br> Coefficient", titlefont = font.pref),
        type = "heatmap") %>%
        layout(xaxis=x.axisSettings,
         yaxis=y.axisSettings,
         plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
         paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
         margin = margins
          )
p
```

And the image this code *used* to produce (note the x and y axis ordering):
[image]

And the script now produces:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values in the new and old heatmaps actually identical; your labels are simply being reordered. This is a strange behavior of the current version of plotly (I'll let others decide whether to call it a "bug"). Axis labels are reordered alphabetically. Here's an MWE that shows it clearly:

```
dat <- matrix(c(1,2,3), nrow = 30, ncol = 30)
dimnames(dat) <- list(rownames(dat, FALSE, "r"), 
                      colnames(dat, FALSE, "c"))
plot_ly(z=dat, x=colnames(dat), y = rownames(dat),
        type = "heat map")
```

Because of this behavior in the current version of plotly, I would suggest using ggplot2 instead. In fact, you can arrive at your original plot in fewer lines as follows:

```
adjwallaceX <- melt(t(as.matrix(adjwallace)))
ggplot(data = adjwallaceX, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
    coord_equal() +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd"))) +
    labs(fill='Adjusted Wallace Coefficient') +
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 315, hjust = 0))
```

[link to new plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I0Tu.png)

Comment: Ah well spotted the data does look right still. I'll investigate the names more closely...

Comment: @JoeHealey figured out what it's doing, and edited my answer as such

Comment: The work around is appreciated, though this strikes me as behaviour that *must* be dictatable within the options of the package itself. I'd like to run the script on several datasets and if I have to manually change all the names everything that kind of defeats the object of a script haha

Comment: Totally agree, though I truly don't see an argument to plot_ly() that will make this possible in an easy way (indeed, I believe x= and y= are supposed to do this, but have unintended behaviors). In such a case, I might opt for ggplot2 heatmaps, from which plotly borrows heavily anyway. Some aesthetic changes to my edited answer with ggplot2 would reproduce your original heatmap nearly identically.

Comment: Lastly, if you _really_ want to use plotly, some of the information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766546/r-plotly-cannot-re-arrange-x-axis-when-axis-type-is-category) should lead you in the right direction

Comment: @JoeHealey Since you haven't yet accepted the answer, I edited the original answer to reproduce the original plot in its entirety with ggplot2. Hope that helps.

Comment: I was going to accept today but thanks, I had only just got a chance to test the code.

Comment: One small follow-up question, what is the `t` denoting in the `melt(t (...` syntax you're using?

Comment: It's transposing the matrix to match the row/column order in your original plot. If you implement without it, the heatmap will be the same, just rotated 90 degrees (for example, the dark vertical stripe at Tree13 will now run horizontally).

Comment: Ah great, that would have been my guess. Thanks once again for the help. I hope plotly actually implement a proper sort soon!

Answer (score 3):

Thought I'd just post a small update to this. I spoke with the devs on GitHub about the 'bug' - and they agreed it's less than ideal behaviour. I think this has now been amended in the dev branch of plotly which can be installed with the `install_github()` method in R, until a new CRAN version is released.

Full thread is here:
https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/863#issuecomment-285761986